# How to move to end of character when switching from normal to insert mode in Emacs Doom or Vim?

Tags: emacs, insert, evil-mode

Emacs-Doom Vim-mod

How to move my box to end of character when switching from normal to insert mode in Emacs Doom Vim-mode?
I am a Doom Emacs newcomer.
What do I need to insert in my config?

Please instruction for noob)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Press a in vim
It's moving one and then changing to insert mode.

Comment: Oh man ! Thanks a lot )) I'm ashamed by my ignorance !

Comment: Don't be! Vim is difficult, with a lot of shortcuts, I recommend trying vimtutor to learn